# is it possible to specify column types when saving a pandas DataFrame to feather?

Tags: python, pandas, feather

Currently, if a column happens to have only nulls, an exception is thrown with the error:

> Invalid: Unable to infer type of object array, were all null

It is possible to specify the type of the column, that will be used instead of inferring the type?

Versions:

```
feather-format==0.3.1
pandas==0.19.1
```

Sample code:

```
feather.write_dataframe(pandas.DataFrame([None]*5), '/tmp/test.feather')
```

Comment: What are your feather-format and pandas versions? Can you post a repoducible example? I couldn't reproduce this error using Pandas 0.19.1 and Feather-Format 0.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change (or replace) `None` to `numpy.nan` and it'll work:

```
In [22]: feather.write_dataframe(pd.DataFrame([np.nan]*5), 'd:/temp/test.feather')

In [23]: feather.read_dataframe('d:/temp/test.feather')
Out[23]:
    0
0 NaN
1 NaN
2 NaN
3 NaN
4 NaN
```

PS NumPy / Pandas / SciPy / etc. have their own representation of Vanilla Python's `None` - `NaN` (Not A Number) or `NaT` (Not A Time for DateTime-like dtypes)